# Выбор записей из таблицы по типу файла

Tags: php, sql

В таблице `upload_files` содержится путь к фотографиям и текстовым документам.
Я делаю выборку для фотографий так:

```
SELECT * FROM `uploаd_files`
WHERE name_pos LIKE '%.jpg'
    OR (`name_pos` LIKE '%.png' OR `name_pos` LIKE '%.gif') 
    AND `ip_users` = '$link' ORDER BY `name_pos` DESC
```

И для документов:

```
SELECT * FROM `upload_files` 
WHERE name_pos NOT LIKE '%.jpg' 
    OR (`name_pos` NOT LIKE '%.png'
    OR `name_pos` NOT LIKE '%.gif') 
    AND `ip_users` = '$link' 
ORDER BY `name_pos` DESC
```

Но результат получается неверный. Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: "но не выходит из за того что не правильно" — совсем ничего не выходит? Опишите что именно происходит.

Comment: Вам может быть полезна вот эта инструкция: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/169)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну а для решения проблемы, думаю, надо скобки переставить:

```
SELECT * FROM `uplod_files`
WHERE (`name_pos` LIKE '%.jpg' OR `name_pos` LIKE '%.png' OR `name_pos` LIKE '%.gif') 
    AND `ip_users` = '$link'
ORDER BY `name_pos` DESC
```

и

```
SELECT * FROM `uplod_files` 
WHERE NOT (`name_pos` LIKE '%.jpg' OR `name_pos` LIKE '%.png' OR `name_pos` LIKE '%.gif') 
    AND `ip_users` = '$link' 
ORDER BY `name_pos` DESC
```

И ещё, я бы исправил `WHERE` следующим образом:

```
WHERE RIGHT(`name_pos`, 3) IN ('jpg', 'png', 'gif') AND `ip_users` = '$link'
```

Ну и соответственно для документов:

```
WHERE NOT RIGHT(`name_pos`, 3) IN ('jpg', 'png', 'gif') AND `ip_users` = '$link'
```

Comment: Там, где у вас пример с NOT LIKE, надо объединять по AND. Булева алгебра, закон де Моргана. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @artoodetoo - виноват. Недоглядел. Исправлено

Comment: Спасибо огромное ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо аккуратнее работать со скобками и отрицанием. Если не знаете приоритетов операций, ставьте скобки. Я напишу псевдокод:

1. графика:
   ((имя похоже на 'А') **ИЛИ** (имя похоже на 'B') **ИЛИ** (имя похоже на 'C')) **И**
   пользователь такой-то
2. не графика:
   **НЕ** ((имя похоже на 'А') **ИЛИ** (имя похоже на 'B') **ИЛИ** (имя похоже на 'C')) **И**
   пользователь такой-то

На самом деле было бы мудрее завести в таблице отдельное поле "mime-type" и проверять его, а не имя файла. Заполнять его один раз при загрузке файла.

```
… WHERE (mime_type LIKE 'image/%')…
```

Answer (score 0):

Процент в лайке в начале строки - плохая практика, данный запрос не попадет в индекс по полю, потому при росте базы запрос будет лавиннобразно есть все больше памяти и выполняться все медленее.